# jQuery Tic Tac Toe Issue

Tags: javascript, jquery

New to jQuery. Not sure why this code isn't working to show wins...

I have 2 click functions one for X and the other for O

Then I have a checkBoard function that checks an array called wins for a matching combination of wins through an array called board.

The table stacks on top of hte jquery code. i have pasted the jquery first because i believe that is where the issue is as i can fill the squares with values but it's not showing wins.

Here is the code:

```
<script>
        var count = 0

        $('td').on('click', function (){
         if(count % 2 === 0){
            $(this).text("X");
        } else {
            $(this).text("O");
        }
            count++
            checkBoard();
        });

        function checkBoard(){

            var wins = [[$("#0"),$("#1"),$("#2")], [$("#3"),$("#4"),$("#5")], [$("#6"),$("#7"),$("#8")], [$("#0"),$("#3"),$("#6")], [$("#1"),$("#4"),$("#7")], [$("#2"),$("#5"),$("#8")], [$("#0"),$("#4"),$("#8")], [$("#6"),$("#4"),$("#2")]]
            var board = [[$("#0"), $("#1"), $("#2")], [$("#3"),$("#4"),$("#5")], [$("#6"), $("#7"), $("#8")]]  


            for(w in this.wins){
             var pattern = this.wins[w];
                var checkPattern = this.board[pattern[0]] + this.board[pattern[1]] + this.board[pattern[2]];
                    if (checkPattern = ["X","X","X"]) {
                        return "X Wins!";
                        console.log("X");
                    } else if (checkPattern = ["O","O","O"]) {
                        return "O Wins!";
                        console.log("O");
                    }
            }
        }

        </script>

<table> 
        <tr>
            <td id="0"></td>
            <td id="1"></td>
            <td id="2"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td id="3"></td>
            <td id="4"></td>
            <td id="5"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td id="6"></td>
            <td id="7"></td>
            <td id="8"></td>
        </tr>
    </table>

td {
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    border: 2px solid black;
    font-size: 5em;
    text-align: center;
}
```

Comment: Start with changing id's. In HTML id starting from a number is invalid.

Comment: change var wins with this.wins same for board

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like the problem is in your for loop. You don't even need the board array, you just check the value of each of jQuery objects in the wins array to see if there is a win.

You were assigning the checkPattern to an array in your if statement when use only use 1 equals sign. Also, using the jQuery selector $(ID) returns a jQuery object, not the contents in the tag.

Try this instead:

```
for (var i=0; i<wins.length; i++) {
                var w = wins[i];
                var checkXwin = w[0].text() == "X" && w[1].text() == "X" && w[2].text() == "X";
                var checkOwin = w[0].text() == "O" && w[1].text() == "O" && w[2].text() == "O";
                if (checkXwin) {
                    console.log("X");
                    return "X Wins!";
                } else if (checkOwin) {
                    console.log("O");
                    return "O Wins!";
                }
            }
```

**EDIT**

I was able to make it work if I used a normal for loop, not an enhanced one.

Comment: this is the error i receive when i use your code: Uncaught TypeError: w[0].val is not a function

Comment: this is the new error: Uncaught TypeError: w[0].text is not a function